# How to match and keep the first number in a line using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

### Question

Let's say I have *one* line of text with a number placed somewhere (it could be at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the line).

How to match and keep the *first* number found in a line using `sed`?

### Minimal example

Here is my attempt (following [this page](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-7) of a tutorial on regular expressions) and the output for different positions of the number:

```
$echo "SomeText 123SomeText" | sed 's:.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*:\1:'
3
$echo "123SomeText" | sed 's:.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*:\1:'
3
$echo "SomeText 123" | sed 's:.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*:\1:'
3
```

As you can only the last digit is kept in the process whereas the desired output should be `123`...

Comment: Do you want to delete all numbers or to get all numbers as output?

Comment: I want to get all numbers as output. I'll try to find a better formulation to my question.

Comment: If you're looking to get all the numbers, `grep -o` is definitely the easiest way to go about it. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24000014/2088135) :)

Comment: No I only want to get the first number: I meant all digits of the first number. Sorry to take so long to accept the answer, I'm very busy at work this week and I have many good answers. It's hard to make a choice so I want to take the time to look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement the `sed` solutions, here's an **`awk` alternative** (assuming that the goal is to extract the *1st* number on each line, if any (i.e., ignore lines without *any* numbers)):

```
awk -F'[^0-9]*' '/[0-9]/ { print ($1 != "" ? $1 : $2) }'
```

- `-F'[^0-9]*'` defines any sequence of non-digit chars. (including the empty string) as the field separator; `awk` automatically breaks each input line into fields based on that separator, with `$1` representing the first field, `$2` the second, and so on.
- `/[0-9]/` is a pattern (condition) that ensures that output is only produced for lines that contain at least one digit, via its associated action (the `{...}` block) - in other words: lines containing NO number at all are ignored.
- `{ print ($1!="" ? $1 : $2) }` prints the 1st field, if nonempty, otherwise the 2nd one; rationale: if the line *starts* with a number, the *1st* field will contain the 1st number on the line (because the line starts with a *field* rather than a *separator*; otherwise, it is the *2nd* field that contains the 1st number (because the line starts with a *separator*).

Comment: +1 for an inventive way of dealing with the problem and a good explanation.

Comment: Even though you don't give an answer with `sed`, I have accepted your answer for the quality of explanations (in your answer and in the comments). 

Thanks @TomFenech for your answer, I had a hard time to chose between both of you and you have been very helpful.

Comment: @remjg I'm glad to hear it; thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Using sed:

```
echo "SomeText 123SomeText 456" | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'
123
```

You can also do this in `gnu awk`:

```
echo "SomeText 123SomeText 456" | awk '{print gensub(/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/, "\\1", $0)}'
123
```

Comment: I didn't know `awk`, thanks. Everything is working well except that the `awk` command is not working if the number is placed at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Perfect, thanks ! I'll try to understand all your answers tonight and I'll accept the easiest.

Comment: +1 for the `sed` solution (use `-E` instead of `-r` to make it work on  BSD/OSX as well as on Linux (GNU `sed`)), but the (revised) `awk` solution doesn't add anything - it's just a clumsier restatement of the `sed` solution. Note that this solution only returns the _1st_ number on each line (as requested in the question), but also passes lines with NO numbers through unmodified (it's unclear what the OP's requirements are in that regard).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use grep, which is ideally suited to this task. sed is a Stream EDitor, which is only going to indirectly give you what you want. With grep, you only have to specify the part of the line you want.

```
$ cat file.txt
SomeText 123SomeText
123SomeText
SomeText 123
$ grep -o '[0-9]\+' file.txt
123
123
123
```

`grep -o` prints only the matching parts of a line, each on a separate line. The pattern is simple: one or more digits.

If your version of grep is compatible with the `-P` switch, you can use Perl-style regular expressions and make the command even shorter:

```
$ grep -Po '\d+' file.txt
123
123
123
```

Again, this matches one or more digits.

Using grep is a lot simpler and has the advantage that if the line doesn't match, nothing is printed:

```
$ echo "no number" | grep -Po '\d+'     # no output
$ echo "yes 123number" | grep -Po '\d+'
123
```

---

#### edit

As pointed out in the comments, one possible problem is that this won't only print the first matching number on the line. If the line contains more than one number, they will all be printed. As far as I'm aware, this can't be done using `grep -o`.

In that case, I'd go with perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*?(\d+).*/'
```

This uses *lazy matching* (the question mark) so only non-digit characters are consumed by the `.*` at the start of the pattern. The `$1` is a back reference, like `\1` in sed. If there are more than one number on the line, this only prints the first. If there aren't any at all, it doesn't print anything:

```
$ echo "no number" | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /.*?(\d+).*/'
$ echo "yes123number456" | perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*?(\d+).*/'
123
```

---

If for some reason you still really want to use sed, you can do this:

```
sed -n 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

unlike the other answers, this is compatible with all version of sed and will only print lines that contain a match.

Comment: Note that `grep -o` _invariably_ prints ALL matches in a given line (as separate output lines); the OP seems to only want the FIRST: `keep the first number found in a line`

Comment: @mklement0 the OP also uses the singular "_a_ number placed somewhere" and uses "or" when referring to the possible position. Nevertheless I take your point. I have edited my answer :)

Comment: +1 for the `perl` solution and the _portable_ `sed` solution. `grep -o` IS handy in general, but marred by the inability to control how many matches _per line_ should be output and, in case of multiples, _how_ they should be output. `awk` also makes it easy to just output the portion of an input line of interest, provided you can conceive of the input as being composed of _fields_ - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed` command,

```
$echo "SomeText 123SomeText" | sed -r '/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*/ s//\1 /g'
123
```

Another example,

```
$ echo "SomeText 123SomeText 456" | sed -r '/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*/ s//\1 /g'
123 456
```

It prints all the numbers in a file and the captured numbers are separated by spaces while printing.

Comment: Thanks ! But the first example doesn't work if the number is at the end of the line. Same if it is at the beginning.

Comment: try `echo "SomeText SomeText123" | sed -r '/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*/ s//\1/g'`

Comment: To clarify this solution's behavior: (a) outputs the 1st number on each line, _unconditionally followed by a space_; if there's (at least) a 2nd number, appends _it plus the remainder of the line_; (b) also outputs lines - unmodified - that contain _no_ numbers at all.
The revised command from a comment extracts _all_ numbers due to using the `s` command's `g` flag, but does so without a separator between numbers. To avoid printing of lines that contain _no_ numbers, add the `-n` option to the `sed` invocation and, inside the `sed` script, add flag `p` to the `s` command.